# How do i check a condition in takeWhile if condition depends on current value and previous value?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a arrayList as follows:

```
[{hours: 48, cancellationCharges: 0}, 
 {hours: 12, cancellationCharges: 10}, 
 {hours: 0, cancellationCharges: 20}]
```

The above array means that from 0 to 12 hours before departure, a cancellation charge of 20% is applicable. From 12 hours to 48 hours before departure, a cancellation charge of 10% is applicable and beyond 48 hours, there is not cancellation charge at all.

I want to filter the above to find out the cancellation charges which are applicable beyond a day. i.e., in the above case, the result should be

```
[{hours: 48, cancellationCharges: 0}, 
 {hours: 12, cancellationCharges: 10}]
```

I tried to filter by condition hours >= 24 and if the last element does not have hours as 24, I iterated again to find the first element with hours < 24. Is there a better way to solve this. I am using java12.

Comment: so ... you have tried. What have you tried?

Comment: as you said 12 to 48hrs is 10% cancellation charge.
So beyond the day means greater than 24hrs. So you need to check greater than 12 hrs as your condition because your hours for that case is 12 hrs as in that JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to keep track of the last "hours" value you've seen. Remember that the `Predicate` that you pass to to `takeWhile` is an object, so you can keep state inside of it. It would look something like this:

```
cancellationRules.takeWhile(new Predicate<CancellationRule> {
    private int previousHours = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    public boolean test(CancellationRule rule) {
        boolean result = rule.hours >= 24 || previousHours >= 24;
        previousHours = rule.hours;
        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: If there are so many cancellation rules that filtering them requires multiple cores and parallel streams, then this business has problems that engineering can't fix. :-)